# Python selecting closest negative and positive values to zero from a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have many lists. Each list constains three floats. I need to select a negative and positive closest to zero from each list. 
Here is the example:

```
list1= [-18.987536121749894, 9.154936510174036, -4.626424654409895]     
list2= [-4.626424654409895, 9.154936510174036, 2.355498340416582]     
list3= [-0.5, 0.1, 0.005]
```

My expected output:

```
list1_op= [-4.626424654409895, 9.154936510174036]     
list2_op= [-4.626424654409895, 2.355498340416582]     
list3_op= [-0.5, 0.005]
```

My code:

```
while loop: 
     ...
     ...
    pdif = fun(mf1,mf2,mf3)   # mf1 and mf2 are extreme points, mf3 is middle point between them
    asign = np.sign(pdif) # check for sign change in Pdif list  
    signchange = ((np.roll(asign, 1) - asign) != 0).astype(int)
    print(pdif)
    if abs(pdif[2])<0.01:
        print("Optimal point reached")
        break
    else:
        if signchange.sum()>0: # If yes then there is a merging point
            if (pdif[2]<abs(pdif[0]))&(signchange[1]==1):
                mf1 = mf3
            elif (pdif[2]<abs(pdif[1]))&(signchange[2]==1):
                mf2 = mf3
            mf3 = np.array([mf1,mf2]).mean()
```

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Can you explain the goal of your code better? You said you need to select one positive and one negative number, is it from the list of 3 you generate in each iteration? 'cause you don't have a negative number in there.

Comment: That's right. My code failed to select right numbers in the starting of 3rd iteration resulting in all positive numbers and  a wrong. I will change my question with a simple example.

Comment: Are you trying to do `a[a>0].min()` and `a[a<0].max()`?

Comment: @Orit I have modified my question. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @wwii I have modified my question. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the largest number less than zero and the smallest number greater than zero.

```
import numpy as np
a = [-18.987536121749894, 9.154936510174036, -4.626424654409895]     
b = [-4.626424654409895, 9.154936510174036, 2.355498340416582]     
c = [-0.5, 0.1, 0.005] 
for thing in (a,b,c):
    thing = np.array(thing)
    x = thing[thing<0].max()
    y = thing[thing>0].min()
    ix = np.where(np.isclose(thing,x))[0]
    iy = np.where(np.isclose(thing,y))[0]
    print(f'{x},{y},{ix},{iy}')
    # or
    indices = np.where(np.any(np.isclose(thing[:,None],[x,y]),axis=-1))
    print(f'indices:{indices[0]}')
```

---

Will throw a ValueError if there are no positive or no negative numbers in the list being tested.

Comment: In addition, How to find the index of corresponding elements?

Comment: [numpy.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) should be the answer.

Comment: @Mainland - use `np.where` and `np.isclose`.

Comment: Finding the index: `thingg.index(thing[thing<0].max())` gives error.

Comment: @Mainland in the loop `thing` is an ndarray not a list. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
output_list = [None]*len(lists)    

for i in len(lists):
    list = lists[i]
    smallest_positive = list[list>0].min()
    biggest_negative = list[list<0].max()
    output_list[i] = (smallest_positive, biggest_negative)
return output_list
```